# Not able to mount Azure File Share on Linux (Ubntu 22.04 LTS) VM during image creation using packer

Tags: azure-devops, ansible, packer, ubuntu-22.04, azure-file-share

I running HCL Packer to create Ubuntu 22.04 LTS image. I'm using `ansible-local` provisioner. The ansible playbook has following tasks (besides many others):

```
share_path: "/var/my_nfs"
tasks:
    - name: Create Share Directory
      become: yes
      file:
        path: "{{ share_path }}"
        state: directory
        mode: 777
        recurse: yes

    - name: Ensure share directory has correct permissions.
      become: true
      file:
        path: "{{ share_path }}"
        state: directory
        owner: www-data
        group: www-data

    - name: Mount File Share
      become: yes
      command: mount -t cifs //{{ storage_account_name }}.file.core.windows.net/{{ file_share_name }} {{ share_path }} -o "username={{ storage_account_name }},password={{ storage_account_key }},dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777,serverino,uid=www-data,gid=www-data"
```

This last task is giving me hard time. I'm consistently getting the following error:

```
"mount error(13): Permission denied",
"Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs) and kernel log messages (dmesg)"
```

I have checked many times, the `storage_account_name`, `file_share_name`, `storage_account_key` are all correct.

I have checked connectivity over 445 port to the file share that is working as well.

Any clue what I'm missing here?

Comment: Are both Packer and Ansible logging verbose?

Comment: Yes, ansible logging is verbose (-vvv) @MattSchuchard

Answer (score 0):

My problem was following 2 things:

1. A faulty startup script changing ownership of everything in /bin directory to some non-root user group.
2. Network connectivity.

I fixed the script and allowed outbound connectivity on port 445. Still not able to mount during image creation but it gets mounted when the VMSS is created or a new instance is spun up.